# css font-face code not working on IE7 / 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-7, font-family

I used font-squirrel to generate web fonts and specify CSS declarations for the font, but it still uses the fallback fonts when I view the page in IE9 using IE7 or IE8 browser and document mode. Any idea what's going on? Here's my code (and a screenshot):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cubanoregular';
    src: url('../fonts/cubano/cubano/../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.svg#../fonts/cubano/cubanoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


.cubano { font-family: 'cubanoregular' }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code you put above is accurate, then the only problem is that your path to the `eot` file is incorrect:

```
src: url('../fonts/cubano/cubano/../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.eot');...
```

Fix that, and it should work fine. IE has supported `@font-face` since version 5 I believe, but in versions prior to 9 only [eot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_OpenType) is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code, the problem seems to be the font. But it's on [Typekit](https://typekit.com/fonts/cubano) if you want.

Comment: I even tried typekit and it's not working...Maybe because I'm looking at this through IE9 in IE7 mode? Because I'm using windows through Parallels on a mac?

Answer (score 0):

check your `src` path is correct

```
src: url('../fonts/cubano/cubano/../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.svg#../fonts/cubano/cubanoregular') format('svg');
```

probably needs to be

```
src: url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/cubano/cubano-regular-webfont.woff-webfont.svg#../fonts/cubano/cubanoregular') format('svg');
```